# Comparing two SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL database of all NCAA basketball tournament results. I'm looking at the "haves" and "have nots" of college hoops, and looking for who drops in and out of the "haves" list by examining NCAA tournament bids over time.

I've got a query that counts the number of NCAA appearances by each team for two sets of years. I want to compare the results for the two sets - seeing who dropped out and who dropped in from one year to the next.

For example, which teams made 6 of 10 NCAA tournaments between 1985-94, which made 6 between 1986-95, and what are the differences in the two lists. Here's what I have:

```
Select t1.Team AS "1994 Teams",t2.Team AS "1995 Teams" 
FROM
(SELECT Count(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME.`Year`) AS 'Totals', TABLE_NAME.Team, TABLE_NAME.Current_Conference
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE TABLE_NAME.`Year` BETWEEN 1985 AND 1994
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME.Team HAVING Totals >= 6
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME.Team) AS t1,

(SELECT Count(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME.`Year`) AS 'Totals', TABLE_NAME.Team, TABLE_NAME.Current_Conference
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE TABLE_NAME.`Year` BETWEEN 1986 AND 1995
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME.Team HAVING Totals >= 6
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME.Team) AS t2
WHERE t1.Team = t2.Team
```

This returns (in this case) 32 records - all the teams that were in 6 of 10 NCAA tournaments in both 1985-94 and 1986-95. I'm trying to find the teams that are in one set and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is using the subquery in the WHERE part:

```
SELECT t1.Team
  FROM (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME.`Year`) AS 'Totals',
                  TABLE_NAME.Team,
                  TABLE_NAME.Current_Conference 
             FROM TABLE_NAME 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME.`Year` BETWEEN 1985 AND 1994 
         GROUP BY TABLE_NAME.Team 
           HAVING Totals >= 6 
         ORDER BY TABLE_NAME.Team
       ) AS t1 
 WHERE t1.team NOT IN (
              SELECT TABLE_NAME.Team 
                FROM TABLE_NAME 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME.`Year` BETWEEN 1986 AND 1995 
            GROUP BY TABLE_NAME.Team 
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME.`Year`) >= 6 )
```

Comment: Thanks - it's not returning the right results for some reason, though. Trying to sift through what it gives me to see what's going wrong. As it is, it returns  no records when there should be three Teams in the 1985-1994 group that aren't in the 1986-95 group ....

Comment: In order to help you with that I will need more information. Can you paste a dump of your table?

Comment: Thank you @tjb1013. I edited the answer and fixed the query. Now it gives the proper results :)